# how to get the list of files from a particular directory using glob in expect scripting

Tags: expect

what I want to get is the list of all the files starting with hello but must belong only to a particular directory in which i am searching.
 I tried

> set files [glob -type f hello*]
>   but i am getting files from all the directories starting with hello.I want those files starting with hello in my current directory.

Comment: That really looks correct - are you sure you are reporting the problem accurately?

Comment: the problem is that I am getting all the files belonging to all the directories starting with hello.But what do I do if I want files starting with hello from one particular directory.commands such as find,etc arent working

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what you're seeing:

```
$ touch helloworld
$ mkdir hello_dir
$ touch hello_dir/file_in_subdir
$ ls -1R .
.:
hello_dir/
helloworld

./hello_dir:
file_in_subdir

$ expect -v
expect version 5.45

$ expect
expect1.1> glob -type f hello*
helloworld
```

Comment: is there any other command that can be used instead of glob to find files containing a particular pattern in expect?

Comment: and what exactly is the path of your file helloworld?

Comment: current directory. You'll have to show us how to reproduce your problem.